# ServiceStack.Ormlite single poco map to many tables

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I know that Servicestack.Ormlite is setup to be a 1:1 mapping between poco and database table.  I have a situation where I will have groups of tables that are of the same structure and they are created as necessary.  I am trying to find a way to be able to do something where I can continue to use the `IDbConnection` and specify the table name in CRUD operations.

Something like

```cs
using(var db = _conn.OpenDbConnection()){
    db.SaveAll(objList, "DIFFERENT_TABLE");
}
```

I was easily able to work around to make creating and deleting the tables.  I am hoping that I can use of the `ExpressionVisitor` or something else to help change the table name before it is executed.  One of the requirements of the project is that it be database agnostic, which  is why I am trying to not manually write out the SQL.

**Solutions**
Here are a couple of functions that I ended up creating if anyone out there wants some more examples.

```cs
public static List<T> SelectTable<T>(this IDbConnection conn, string tableName) {
        var stmt = ModelDefinition<T>.Definition.SqlSelectAllFromTable;
        stmt = stmt.Replace(ModelDefinition<T>.Definition.Name, tableName.FmtTable());
        return conn.Select<T>(stmt);
}

public static List<T> SelectTableFmt<T>(this IDbConnection conn, string tableName, string sqlFilter,
        params object[] filterParams) {
        var stmt = conn.GetDialectProvider().ToSelectStatement(typeof (T), sqlFilter, filterParams);
        stmt = stmt.Replace(ModelDefinition<T>.Definition.Name, tableName.FmtTable());
        return conn.Select<T>(stmt);
}

public static void InsertTable<T>(this IDbConnection conn, T obj, string tablename) {
        var stmt = conn.GetDialectProvider().ToInsertRowStatement(null, obj);
        stmt = stmt.Replace(obj.GetType().Name, tablename.FmtTable());
        conn.ExecuteSql(stmt);
}

public static int SaveAll<T>(this IDbConnection conn, string tablename, IEnumerable<T> objs) {
        var saveRows = objs.ToList();
        var firstRow = saveRows.FirstOrDefault();
        if (Equals(firstRow, default(T))) return 0;

        var defaultIdValue = firstRow.GetId().GetType().GetDefaultValue();

        var idMap = defaultIdValue != null
            ? saveRows.Where(x => !defaultIdValue.Equals(x.GetId())).ToSafeDictionary(x => x.GetId())
            : saveRows.Where(x => x.GetId() != null).ToSafeDictionary(x => x.GetId());

        var existingRowsMap = conn.SelectByIds<T>(tablename, idMap.Keys).ToDictionary(x => x.GetId());
        var modelDef = ModelDefinition<T>.Definition;
        var dialectProvider = conn.GetDialectProvider();

        var rowsAdded = 0;

        using (var dbTrans = conn.OpenTransaction()) {
            foreach (var obj in saveRows) {
                var id = obj.GetId();

                if (id != defaultIdValue && existingRowsMap.ContainsKey(id)) {
                    var updStmt = dialectProvider.ToUpdateRowStatement(obj);
                    updStmt = updStmt.Replace(obj.GetType().Name, tablename.FmtTable());
                    conn.ExecuteSql(updStmt);
                }
                else {
                    if (modelDef.HasAutoIncrementId) {}
                    var stmt = dialectProvider.ToInsertRowStatement(null, obj);

                    stmt = stmt.Replace(obj.GetType().Name, tablename.FmtTable());

                    conn.ExecuteSql(stmt);

                    rowsAdded++;
                }
            }

            dbTrans.Commit();
        }
        return rowsAdded;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrmLite supports specifying the table name for Update and Delete operations. Unfortunately the examples in the [readme here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/README.md) have yet to be updated. This is the required format:

UPDATE:

```cs
db.UpdateFmt(table: "Person", set: "FirstName = {0}".Fmt("JJ"), where: "LastName = {0}".Fmt("Hendrix"));
```

DELETE:

```cs
db.DeleteFmt(table: "Person", where: "Age = {0}".Fmt(27));
```

The methods you need can be [found here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/Expressions/WriteConnectionExtensions.cs). You should be able to use `.Exec` to handle reading and insert operations.

Comment: That does work in ServiceStack 3.9.71.  It is not working in ServiceStack 4.0.6

Comment: @mnfact That's odd it should still work. I need to take a look over the latest release of the code and see whats changed.

Comment: I'll take a look too.  Chances are it just slipped through the conversion.